# How to maintain timestamp in various countries

Tags: php, javascript

I have a problem with timestamp. Suppose a user uploads a picture somewhere in USA at 4.30 am and if another user sees this picture in Japan. It would show 4.30 am as the date saved in database would be 4.30 am but it should be 4.30 pm to the Japanese people, as they are 12 hours  ahead of America.

So I was thinking to get the current server time using PHP, let's say it is `a` and also get the current time of user using JavaScript functions  say it is `b` and then find the difference between `b` and `a` and that result should be added to the date stored in the database.

So server may show 4.30 am and js function gives 4.30 pm it would give 12 hrs difference so this 12 hrs should be added to the date saved in the database.This is what I thought of doing but I'm not sure if there are any inbuilt plugins in doing the task because every site will be using this type of feature may be they might be using someone's open source code.

Also there might be any other better solutions? And is my algorithm right? I was thinking it is little bit time consuming getting the difference and adding those to all the posts would be little time consuming.

Comment: Your solution should work provided there is only one server and no day light saving. If there are multiple servers located in different geographic regions, you need to consider the time zone from where the file was uploaded and not just the server time. Also, there are scenarios where day light saving may be applicable in one region but not in another region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store all time stamps as UTC. Then for the user interface do the correction for the particular time zone for the user. You can also take into account day light savings if necessary

Answer (score 1):

Can you look up the time at GMT+0 when you upload, then when it is downloaded, convert to the local time. This explains timezones: http://hutch120.blogspot.com.au/2008/03/php-timezones-explained.html

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to transform all local times to the server time and keep dates in the db just in one timezone. This helps to do calculations. I also keep the timezone information about the original entry and you can have a user setting with the preferred timezone of the client and show them the time in whatever timezone they want.